# Installing OS from external hard drive without formatting it

Tags: installation, external-hard-drive, operating-systems

I've a 1 terabyte WD external hard drive and there are images of Linux OS on it, is there any way to boot them from this external drive without formatting all 1 terabyte space?(there are many file within it and I don't want to format it.)

currently I'm running windows 7 and I want to install ubuntu from the external drive(without formatting it.)

Comment: Provided they are a bootable ISO, yes. From which system do you start from? You may find interesting [How to boot from a USB device using an ISO image](http://superuser.com/questions/308635/how-to-boot-from-a-usb-device-using-an-iso-image). Did you want to install the OS from that external drive to the system?

Comment: @Hastur, currently I've windows 7 and I want to install Ubuntu or other Linux distribution along side windows 7. and yes, I want to install the ubuntu from external drive.How I can create a bootable iso without formatting the drive?

Answer (score 2):

[Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) can make your external drive bootable with certain ISOs without formatting the drive - it keeps all the data and adds the MBR to it, along with some unpacked folders and files from the ISO. But be careful, it has an option to *format the drive*, tick that checkbox before pressing *next*.

If you want to install Ubuntu in a normal way, to separate the partition, then you'll need to write your ISO to CD/DVD/USB and then boot from it (you'll have to tell the BIOS about it). If you have had any linux distribution previously installed, you could add a boot menu entry to the GRUB and tell it to run certain ISO image from a specific drive.

Do you want to install Ubuntu to the same Windows partition? Because with [WUBI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi) you can install Ubuntu to a Windows partition alongside with your current Windows, just by running all stuff from Windows. See the link I put on WUBI.